# AirDrop iOS 7 new feature

Tags: ios7, airdrop

I am trying to implement `AirDrop` feature in my iOS Application. However, I am unable to find any specific tutorial or resources regarding this feature.  Can someone please provide me with a sample, or a link, regarding the implementation of the `AirDrop` feature in iOS 7?

Any help is highly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Airdrop is a feature that was added to the currently available [UIActivityViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIActivityViewController).  If a user has iOS7 on a supported device (iPad mini, iPad 4, iPhone 5, iPhone 5c, iPhone 5s), then airdrop should be available to them as just another option, unless you explicitly exclude that activity.

Answer (score 5):

Try this, its built in feature. Do this in your button selector.

```
UIDocumentInteractionController *interaction = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileToTransferPath]];
//fileToTransferPath can be the path of a file supported by airdrop feature.
interaction.delegate = self;
[interaction presentOpenInMenuFromRect:sender.frame inView:self.view animated:NO];
```

Don't forget to add UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate in .h file.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me, please elaborate what file types are supported by `AirDrop` ?

Comment: You can only use a few file types. From the docs "When using this service, you can provide NSString, NSAttributedString, UIImage, ALAsset, and NSURL objects as data for the activity items. You may also specify NSURL objects whose contents use the assets-library scheme." So essentially a string, URL, or an image. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivity_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIActivity

Comment: The URL could either be a web-link, custom scheme url (ex: yelp://) or a file URL to any file type. So to answer the question "what file types are supported?": All file types are supported.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you want to share a URL with someone. You can do it like this using the UIActivityViewController:

```
// Build a collection of activity items to share, in this case a url
NSArray *activityItems = @[[NSURL URLWithString:link]];

// Build a collection of custom activities (if you have any)
NSMutableArray *customActivities = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:customActivities];

[self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This would also give you access to other social sharing functions automatically, unless you disable them through the customActivities collection.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: You would want to use the `excludedActivityTypes` property on `UIActivityViewController` to "disable" activities. The `applicationActivities:` argument to the init method is to add additional activities (your own UIActivity subclasses).